# image display as gridview

Tags: android, image, url, gridview

i want to display images from mysql server(testing in localhost) using imageurl,i have images in a filder on my server,in an android client app as gridview along with text.how do i use imageurl in my code?
mymainmenu.java

```
public class MainMenu extends Activity {



    GridView gridView;

    static final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { 
        "Android", "iOS","Windows", "Blackberry" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu_list);


        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                   getApplicationContext(),
                   ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label))
                   .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

my imageadapter.java:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private final String[] mobileValues;
    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] mobileValues) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mobileValues = mobileValues;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View gridView;

    if (convertView == null) {

        gridView = new View(context);

        // get layout from list.xml
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

        // set value into textview
        TextView textView = (TextView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
        textView.setText(mobileValues[position]);

        // set image based on selected text
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

        String mobile = mobileValues[position];

        if (mobile.equals("Windows")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imggrid);
        } else if (mobile.equals("iOS")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imggrid);
        } else if (mobile.equals("Blackberry")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imggrid);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.imggrid);
        }

    } else {
        gridView = (View) convertView;
    }

    return gridView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mobileValues.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
```

}

I dnt know how to use the following in my code:

```
try {
            URL url = new URL(imageFileURL);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();                   
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();               
            if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
             InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();                     
             Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
             inputStream.close();
             img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
           } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
           }
```

Comment: thanks in advance..someone pls help

Comment: What's the exact prob? Are you getting any errors? If yes then pls post logcat.

Comment: Go and try with [**Android - Universal Image loader**](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Comment: this code is working properly for a defined number of images and texts.But what I need is to display all the images retrieved from server, as gridview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image downloading code in a `AsyncTask`. [Here is the explanation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). 
Execute one instance of asynctask in your getView method, i.e to fetch one image everytime.

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
 ImageView mImageView;
 public void setImageView(ImageView img) {
      mImageView = img;
 }

 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
     return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
     mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
 }
```

}

Call `task.setImageView(yourImageViewinGrid)` before executing your `AsyncTask` to let it know where to set the image after downloading.

Comment: thank you @userSeven7s ,but I have nearly 10 images at present and the number may increase on updating at server. so can u please tell me how to retrieve all the picture being put on a specific folder on server can be downloaded and displayed at the same time on my client app? I need to incorporate some texts along with each image as the item name.This the,on a click should open another activity.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

> I dnt know how to use the following in my code:

that code will download the image for you, you can place in separate thread either `AsyncTask` or `Thread` and set the downloaded image in the imageview... simple as that. There are so many example on the web you can google it out

**EIDTED**

code to download the image

```
public class AsyncFetchImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>{

    private WeakReference<ImageView> imageReference;
//  private WeakReference<Dialog> dialogReferance;

    public AsyncFetchImage(ImageView imageview) {
        imageReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageview);
//      dialogReferance = new WeakReference<Dialog>(dialog);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... s) {

        return downloadImage(s[0]);
    }

    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {

        final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Nixit");
        final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
        try {

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url); 
                return null;
            }
            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if(entity != null){
                InputStream is = null;
                try{
                    is = entity.getContent();
                    final Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                    return bit;
                }finally{
                    if(is != null)
                        is.close();
                    entity.consumeContent();
                }
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally{
            if(client != null){
                client.close();
            }
        }
        Log.i("Image Fetch","Image Fetch Complete");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if(isCancelled()){
            result = null;
        }
        if(imageReference != null){
            ImageView imageView = imageReference.get();
//          Dialog di = dialogReferance.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
//                di.show();
            }

        }
    }


}
```

How to use:-

```
imageView = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

AsyncFetchImage fetchImage = new AsyncFetchImage(imageView);
fetchImage.execute(url);
```

You can use this in getview method of adapter

Hope that help

Comment: thank you @Nixit Patel..I tried several examples,but none works for me..can u show me how to incorporate that url code section into my mainmenu and imageadapter classes?that will be more helpful

Comment: thanx @Nixit Patel..but i am not able to configure my imageadapter class.If you don't mind, tell me exactly how to modify my mainmenu class..you may edit mainmenu class for a clear understanding..

Comment: @ess.crazy In adapter class you have method getView(...) and in tha getView method add the code "How to use" from my update,

Comment: still getting errors @Nixit..pls copy paste here the code imageadapter class code according to ur idea

Comment: some sort of errors when putting your code inside the imageadapter, I am unable to set the class..so please show me exactly how to modify that imageadapter class.should change the layoutinflater and all?pls edit that imageadapter code for me in the correct way as ur opinion

Answer (score 0):

To get the image, you have to do something like :

```
URL new_url = new URL("your url"); 
Bitmap image_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection() .getInputStream()); ImageView image_view = new ImageView(this);
image_view.setImageBitmap(image_bitmap);
```

Anyway, it's better to download the image as background task. What I actually do is to create a custom view with one private inner class that extend AsyncTask to download the image for you.

Comment: Thank you @Warut Surapat..can u show me how to display those retrieved images in my gridview?pls edit the code for me